Rigify quadruped rigging error: Incorrect armature for type "skin_jaw"
UPDATE - SOLVED
I fixed the problem by re-doing the rig, and making sure that no snapped bones are disconnected in the process, while also making sure that I apply transforms every step of the way.
I'm trying to create a rigify setup for this bad boy:

And when I click on Create Rig I get this error message:

I did some research and tried my best to fix it with the available information, I learned that it is probably related to some disconnected facial bones, so I obviously checked the ones that the error message points to, however, I can't seem to fix it even after snapping them together. Or maybe I'm not doing things right.
How can I fix it?
Blend:  https://we.tl/t-PnuVpsKzqH

Here the blend file: https://we.tl/t-PnuVpsKzqH

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any mo

Your topology is too dense, also you need to apply the scale of your objects. Select both the armature and object, scale x5, apply the rotation and scale of both your 2 objects, parent the object to the armature, scale down /5, apply the scale again.

hey there, thanks for your comment. I followed up as per your instructions, however, after doing it and trying again, the error remains.

mmh that's weird, it works fine for me, maybe try a Merge by Distance in Edit mode?

Well, that also doesn't seem to fix it, you're saying that it did generate the rig for you after these steps? Maybe I'm just doing things wrong.

Oops sorry I missed that, I just did a simple parent between the object and the metarig, I'm not familiar with Rigify I hope someone will find the problem. I leave my answer though as it fixes the problem with the metarig

I fixed the problem by re-doing the rig, and making sure that no snapped bones are disconnected in the process, while also making sure that I apply transforms every step of the way.
